Update large amount of data in MySQL taking too much time
I have a CSV file data.csv with columns id;new_income.
I want to update an existing table mydb.users which has the columns id, name, and income. The users table already contains all the ids present in data.csv. I need to update the income column in the users table with the new_value from data.csv, matching on id.
Is it possible to use the LOAD DATA INFILE command to update existing rows in the table based on the id field?
The problem is that running an UPDATE query is taking too long. My CSV file has 60M+ rows and my users table has more than 250M+ rows.
I'm using MySQL.
The id column is the primary key in the users table.
I already tried to import the CSV file into a temporary table and run an UPDATE query UPDATE mydb.users AS users INNER JOIN temp_data AS temp ON users.id = temp.id SET users.income = temp.new_income; but it's just taking too much time!! Are there another way to do it?
When I imported my CSV file to the temporary table, I used the `LOAD DATA INFILE...` command, and it took not even 10 minutes to import all the 60M rows from the file into the temporary table. I also created indexes on both tables at id columns before running the update query.

No, load data can onlu be used to insert data into a table. Alternative to load data is to use csv tabke engine in mysql and point the table to the csv file you have, and then use the update statement.

LOAD DATA INFILE has a REPLACE option, so if the primary key of the row it loads already exists in the table, it replaces the row. Read the manual for syntax and further details. I don't know if it'll make it significantly faster, though. You may just need to bear with the speed it can update rows. Or get a more powerful database server.
